# Python multi threading py2exe

Tags: python, python-2.7

actually my question is parallelization implementation in python is through multiprocessing but if implement the multithreading parallelization can't be achieved. if we convert to py2exe does it works like parallel execution.

Thank you in advance

Comment: You could write a simple 2-3 lines code that will test that, what did you try? How is your multi-threaded code built? So much details missing here....

Answer (score 0):

Py2exe does not change the underlying operation of Python, so using it will not sidestep the issue. The multiprocessing module may be the best option.